# git not detecting single-bit error in a tracked file

Tags: git

I recently discovered a single-bit error in a binary file that was included in a Git repository:

```
$ diff <(xxd old-clone/file) <(xxd new-clone/file)
< 00251230: 0412 c2bd 2e61 efeb 21b4 d904 3388 2539
---
> 00251230: 0412 c0bd 2e61 efeb 21b4 d904 3388 2539
```

Concerningly, git had *not* detected that anything was awry. I only found the problem because one of our tests had mysteriously begun to fail, without any committed changes.

When I did a fresh clone of the repository from the server, the test passed again. I now have a situation where I have two copies of the repo, both checked out at the same commit and both reporting a clean working tree, but with clearly different versions of this file:

```
$ cd old-clone && git status && cd ..
HEAD detached at 251265a4
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ cd new-clone && git status && cd ..
HEAD detached at 251265a4
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ diff old-clone/file new-clone/file
Binary files old-clone/file and new-clone/file differ
```

I've confirmed that:

1. This file is definitely being tracked (not in `.gitignore`, not marked `--assume-unchanged`)
2. `git fsck` reports no issues in either repo

My understanding was that this is supposed to be [impossible](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F):

> Git Has Integrity: Everything in Git is checksummed before it is stored and is then referred to by that checksum. This means it’s impossible to change the contents of any file or directory without Git knowing about it. This functionality is built into Git at the lowest levels and is integral to its philosophy. You can’t lose information in transit or get file corruption without Git being able to detect it.

My belief in git's ability to maintain data integrity has been severely shaken.

How can this happen? And how can I ensure that it doesn't happen again (ideally without having to do a fresh clone of the entire repo every time)?

Comment: My first guess is that your hard drive is failing. Every kind of hard drive essentially has a maximum life expectancy, and as it approaches that age, bits will begin to flip on their own -- even if the drive is unpowered. Perhaps more realistically, you've got a handful of bad sectors on an otherwise-healthy disk. Run a drive-checker, and consult your SMART data.

Comment: Besides de disk failure described by @Tom above, git stores a cache of file status linked to the file timestamp, I think. So a change of data content without a corresponding metadata update will fly under git's radar and go unchecked.

Comment: @Tom - I checked the SMART status of the drive and it reports "OK", I also ran `chkdsk` (this is a Windows NTFS drive) and it "found no problems".

Comment: @rodrigo – Is there some way of forcing git to check the actual data content on the drive?

Comment: Then, it sounds like `git fsck` should detect this, as a [**hash mismatch**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck#Documentation/git-fsck.txt-hashmismatchltobjectgt).

Comment: I did run `git fsck` and it reported no issues (other than some dangling commits, which I assume are unrelated?).

Comment: @deltacrux *Is there some way of forcing git to check the actual data content on the drive?* Yes, change the time stamp of every file, then run `git status`, and it will re-hash every file so that the file will be listed as modified. Use, e.g., `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 touch`.

Comment: @j6t – That's a clever idea, unfortunately I can't test it because the issue has magically resolved itself (see my comment to Tom's answer below). I'm considering adding it to our CI workflow now though, out of sheer paranoia. Thanks!

Comment: @j6t – I've confirmed that your suggestion does work, see the answer posted below. I'm surprised that this is the best way to re-index the working tree though, it feels like git should have a dedicated command for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to insightful comments from @rodrigo, @Tom and @j6t, I believe this question has now been answered.

### How did the bit flip?

There are many potential causes of single-bit errors (a.k.a. "bit rot") on hard drives. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/77710/is-bit-rot-on-hard-drives-a-real-problem-what-can-be-done-about-it), and the related links, give a good summary. Importantly, the drive does *not* need to be failing for single-bit errors to occur. As in this case, the S.M.A.R.T. system and tools such as `fsck` or `chkdsk` can report no problems, both before and after such errors occur.

It is also possible that the bit did not flip on the hard drive itself, but rather in a cache somewhere in volatile memory, perhaps as a result of a [single-event upset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-event_upset). This could explain why the bit appeared to flip back after some time, when the cache was refreshed.

### Why didn't git notice?

The error most likely happened in the working tree, and git did not notice because the file's stat information (size, modification time, etc) had not changed.

Since hashing the contents of every file in a large repository can be time-consuming, git "cheats" by serving cached status info based on metadata, rather than always looking at file contents. This means that a change of data content without a corresponding metadata update will fly under git's radar and go unchecked.

This can be easily verified as follows:

```
$ echo "All good" > file.txt

$ git add file.txt && git commit -am "Good file"
[main 1a2b3c4d] Good file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ touch -r file.txt /tmp/timestamp-backup

$ echo 'CORRUPT!' > file.txt

$ touch -r /tmp/timestamp-backup file.txt

$ git log --oneline | head -1
1a2b3c4d Good file

$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ cat file.txt 
CORRUPT!
```

Once in this state, git will not notice that the file is corrupt until it is modified again, either in the working tree or by checking out a commit that changes it.

Note that if the error had occurred in git's object database (`.git/objects`), then running `git fsck` likely would have detected it (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521143/git-fsck-full-only-checking-directories) for more details).

### How can such errors be detected reliably?

On systems where data integrity is important, the possibility of such an error going unnoticed may be unacceptable.

The best solution is to use hardware (e.g. RAID arrays) and/or filesystems (e.g. zfs) that are designed to prevent silent data corruption.

If changing hardware/filesystems is not an option, then for git repositories specifically:

1. Run `git fsck` to verify the object database.
2. Run `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 touch` to force git to re-index the working tree. This command changes the timestamp of every tracked file so that next time `git status` is run, git will re-hash every file and pick up any changes.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed to this question. I've gathered together the information from the various comments into this community wiki answer, please feel free to edit and improve it.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the `--full` option

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521143/git-fsck-full-only-checking-directories) is related: somebody is deliberately modifying file contents in the object database (as a test) and expecting git to find it. It was not finding the corruption, until they added the `--full` arg. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521143/git-fsck-full-only-checking-directories#comment70248714_41521370) below the accepted answer for explicit verification.

What puzzles me is that the [official docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck#Documentation/git-fsck.txt---full) state that "full" is now the default, which is why I didn't suggest this earlier. I did not look to see when that changed, but I suppose it's possible that you're using a version of git that does not default to "full" mode.

I suppose it is also possible that git treats implied "full" differently than explicit "full," although I consider that very unlikely.

Comment: Showing it as a new modification seems like the correct behavior: I think fsck only examines the object database, not the inflated copy in the workspace. If the bit flipped in the database, git should recognize it as corruption. If the bit flipped in the workspace, git should recognize it as an unstaged change -- whether it flipped by human hand or divine intervention, git can't know and shouldn't care.

Comment: I suspect this means that what you need is not a better understanding of `git fsck`, but `git status`. It does seem clear that `git status` wasn't doing a byte-for-byte analysis of your binary file, which is not what we assumed (but also might be a deliberate design choice for binary files).

Comment: @Tom – My reading of that question is different: the OP seems to have been using `--full` all along (it's in the initial question), but was initially _appending_ to the file, which as @John Szakmeister noted will not actually corrupt the object. In the comment you linked to, the OP says that `git fsck --full` detected a change in the _middle_ of the file, which is consistent with the above.

Comment: It seems that `--full` became the default in git version 1.6.6 [(link to release notes)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.6.txt). I am using git version 2.37 (2.37.0.windows.1), so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: @Tom – _If the bit flipped in the database, git should recognize it as corruption._ – Just to confirm, git should recognize this as corruption only when `git fsck` is run. _If the bit flipped in the workspace, git should recognize it as an unstaged change._ If what @rodrigo wrote above is true, then git will _not_ recognize this as a change because the file's metadata stats will not have changed. Even running `git fsck` won't detect this if it only examines the object database, as you say.

Comment: Agreed. It seems like the fact you and I were unaware of is that `git status` cheats by serving cached status info based on metadata, rather than always looking at file contents. Which does seem to somewhat undercut the quote you highlighted about it being impossible for data to change without git noticing.

Comment: Indeed. So it seems the most likely explanation is that a random bit flip occurred in the working tree, which neither `git diff` nor `git fsck` can see (at least not without doing a fresh clone of the repo). A bit scary...

Comment: See [j6t's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73480629/git-not-detecting-single-bit-error-in-a-tracked-file/73481605?noredirect=1#comment129766264_73480629) for a clever workaround that doesn't require re-cloning. Still no solution for detection, though.

Comment: Well, I was going to try the `--full` flag anyway just to be thorough, but first I ran `git fsck` without the flag again (for the 5th time since this issue started). Yet again it reported no problems – but now the bit has _flipped back_! I wouldn't believe it myself if I weren't staring at a terminal with all the previous "Binary files differ" results still in the window.

Answer (score 1):

Git has the correct data stored. But when you have previously fetched a tree it does not have a way to verify the files are correct.

There are a number of ways this can happen, but most boil down to on-disk bit-rot. If your filesystem has checksum system (zfs) you can be notified of this when you read the file (if you have no redundancy) or when you perform monthly scrubs (with redundancy).

You shouldn't be able to download the error (even with a tcp/networking double bit error) because git should verify the checksum when downloaded.